# MySQL groupby with sum

Tags: mysql

I have a query with group by and sum. I have close to 1 million records. When i run the query it is taking 2.5s. If i remove the group by clause it is taking 0.89s. Is there any way we can optimize the query using group by and sum together.

```
 SELECT aggEI.ei_uuid AS uuid,aggEI.companydm_id AS companyId,aggEI.rating AS       rating,aggEI.ei_name AS name,
 compdm.company_name AS companyName,sum(aggEI.count) AS activity
      FROM AGG_EXTERNALINDIVIDUAL AS aggEI
      JOIN COMPANYDM AS compdm ON aggEI.companydm_id = compdm.companydm_id
      WHERE aggEI.ei_uuid is not null
        and aggEI.companydm_id IN (8)
        and aggEI.datedm_id = 20130506 
        AND aggEI.topicgroupdm_id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
        AND aggEI.rating >= 0
        AND aggEI.rating <= 100
 GROUP BY aggEI.ei_uuid,aggEI.companydm_id
LIMIT 0,200000
```

Explain result is as below:

```
  1 SIMPLE  compdm  const   PRIMARY,companydm_id_UNIQUE,comp_idx    PRIMARY 8       const   1   Using temporary; Using filesort
  1 SIMPLE  aggEI   ref       PRIMARY,datedm_id_UNIQUE,agg_ei_comdm_fk_idx,agg_ei_datedm_fk_idx,agg_ei_topgrp_fk_idx,uid_comp_ei_dt_idx,uid_comp_dt_idx,comp_idx    datedm_id_UNIQUE    4   const   197865  Using where
```

Also i didn't understand why compdm table is executed first. Can someone explain?

I have index on AGG_EXTERNALINDIVIDUAL table with combination of ei_uuid,companydm_id,datedm_id. The same is shown on aggEI table under possible keys as uid_comp_dt_idx. But aggEI table is taking datedmid_UNIQUE as key. I didn't understand the behavior.

Can someone explain?

Comment: Query optimization is not my strength but it seems as though a compound index only on (companydm_id,datedm_id,topicgroupdm_id,rating) would help.

Answer (score 1):

Explain has to run the dependent queries before it can run the main one.

You need to check indexing on AGG_EXTERNALINDIVIDUAL.

Comment: Which combination of index will increase the performance. I have the index for the combination of columns used in where and group by clause. aggEI.ei_uuid,aggEI.companydm_id,aggEI.datedm_id,aggEI.topicgroupdm_id

Comment: You have indexes on the individual columns, but the explain shows it's only using datedm_id_UNIQUE, and it looks through 197,865 records.  If this query is run on a regular basis, you can create an index on multiple columns at once.

Comment: I have defined compound index test_idx -> (uuid,companydm_id,datedm_id,topicgroupdm_id,rating). But the result is same. Explain still shows datedm_id_UNIQUE as the key.Is there any other way to optimize this query.

Comment: I think the fact that UUID has the ability to be NULL might be causing trouble (even though you're filtering it out.)  Otherwise, I'm at a loss.

Comment: I have added uuid null check to use the index defined. But the performance is same even if i remove the condition. UUID is varchar. Will grouping on that columns cause problem

Comment: Any clues why index on columns with range are not considered in execution plan. In my case execution plan is looking for index starting with date but not ei_uuid,companydm_id